# Why does SSLSocket.startHandshake() offers a callback if it is synchronous ?

Tags: java, ssl, handshake

The javadoc for method [`SSLSocket.startHandshake()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#startHandshake()) says that the method is synchronous.

However, the "see also" section offers a callback for the "handshakeComplete" event : [`HandshakeCompletedListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#addHandshakeCompletedListener(javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener)).

Why would it be useful to have such a callback if the method returns right after the handshake is completed ?

Does it mean that if I write this code

```
SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("localhost", 8888);
c.startHandshake();

BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
c.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
c.getInputStream()));
w.write("I am client " + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
w.newLine();
```

I am not guaranteed to write in the outputStream only if the handshake is completed ?

Comment: The docs state *"This method is synchronous for the **initial** handshake on a connection and returns when the negotiated handshake is complete. Some protocols may not support **multiple handshakes** on an existing socket and may throw an IOException."*, that should be a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does SSLSocket.startHandshake() offers a callback if it is synchronous?

It isn't always synchronous.

> The javadoc for method SSLSocket.startHandshake() says that the method is synchronous.

No it doesn't. It says that it is synchronous *for the initial handshake.*

> However, the "see also" section offers a callback for the "handshakeComplete" event : HandshakeCompletedListener.

Correct.

> Why would it be useful to have such a callback if the method returns right after the handshake is completed?

*Non sequitur.*. A callback is always useful, and the method doesn't always return right after the handshake is completed.

See the Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll have a look at this

Comment: You should probably differentiate between *"initial handshake"* and other types (stages?) of handshakes. Are the docs talking about session tickets, session resumption and TLS 1.3's 0-RTT? Or something else?

Comment: @jww There is no need whatsoever to distinguish any further than 'initial' and 'non-initial'. It is already perfectly clear.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance (its not perfectly clear to me as a reader)... what is the significance of the word *initial*? If they are talking about the whole handshake, then why is the word *initial* used? What portion of the handshake is being described with the word *initial*?

Comment: @jww No 'portion'. The entire handshake. The entire initial handshake. The entire handshake that is done when initializing the TLS connection. You're creating difficulties where none exist.